# Why is JMH saying that returning 1 is faster than returning 0

Tags: java, performance, benchmarking, jmh

Can someone explain why JMH saying that returning 1 is faster than returning 0 ?

Here is the benchmark code.

```
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.*;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

@State(Scope.Thread)
@BenchmarkMode(Mode.Throughput)
@OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
@Fork(value = 3, jvmArgsAppend = {"-server", "-disablesystemassertions"})
public class ZeroVsOneBenchmark {

    @Benchmark
    @Warmup(iterations = 3, time = 2, timeUnit = TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    public int zero() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Benchmark
    @Warmup(iterations = 3, time = 2, timeUnit = TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    public int one() {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Here is the result:

```
# Run complete. Total time: 00:03:05

Benchmark                       Mode   Samples        Score  Score error    Units
c.m.ZeroVsOneBenchmark.one     thrpt        60  1680674.502    24113.014   ops/ms
c.m.ZeroVsOneBenchmark.zero    thrpt        60   735975.568    14779.380   ops/ms
```

The same behaviour for one, two and zero

```
# Run complete. Total time: 01:01:56

Benchmark                       Mode   Samples        Score  Score error    Units
c.m.ZeroVsOneBenchmark.one     thrpt        90  1762956.470     7554.807   ops/ms
c.m.ZeroVsOneBenchmark.two     thrpt        90  1764642.299     9277.673   ops/ms
c.m.ZeroVsOneBenchmark.zero    thrpt        90   773010.467     5031.920   ops/ms
```

Comment: Hey I was creating baseline and saw this behaviour, it's not that I'm spending my time to measure just this example. it's simplified version for this thread.

Comment: Then create a non-simplified version showing what you see.  Needs to be complex enough that all the Hotspot work is insignificant related to what you want to measure.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

JMH is a good tool but still not perfect.

Certainly there is no speed difference between returning 0, 1 or any other integer. However it makes difference how the value is *consumed* by JMH and how this is compiled by HotSpot JIT.

To prevent JIT from optimizing out calculations, JMH uses the special [Blackhole](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/code-tools/jmh/file/f60971abb85c/jmh-core/src/main/java/org/openjdk/jmh/infra/Blackhole.java) class to *consume* values returned from a benchmark. [Here is](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/code-tools/jmh/file/f60971abb85c/jmh-core/src/main/java/org/openjdk/jmh/infra/Blackhole.java#l344) a one for integer values:

```
public final void consume(int i) {
    if (i == i1 & i == i2) {
        // SHOULD NEVER HAPPEN
        nullBait.i1 = i; // implicit null pointer exception
    }
}
```

Here `i` is a value returned from a benchmark. In your case it is either 0 or 1. When `i == 1` the never-happen condition looks like `if (1 == i1 & 1 == i2)` which is compiled as follows:

```
0x0000000002b4ffe5: mov    0xb0(%r13),%r10d   ;*getfield i1
0x0000000002b4ffec: mov    0xb4(%r13),%r8d    ;*getfield i2
0x0000000002b4fff3: cmp    $0x1,%r8d
0x0000000002b4fff7: je     0x0000000002b50091  ;*return
```

But when `i == 0` JIT tries to "optimize" two comparisions to `0` using `setne` instructions. However the result code becomes too complicated:

```
0x0000000002a40b28: mov    0xb0(%rdi),%r10d   ;*getfield i1
0x0000000002a40b2f: mov    0xb4(%rdi),%r8d    ;*getfield i2
0x0000000002a40b36: test   %r10d,%r10d
0x0000000002a40b39: setne  %r10b
0x0000000002a40b3d: movzbl %r10b,%r10d
0x0000000002a40b41: test   %r8d,%r8d
0x0000000002a40b44: setne  %r11b
0x0000000002a40b48: movzbl %r11b,%r11d
0x0000000002a40b4c: xor    $0x1,%r10d
0x0000000002a40b50: xor    $0x1,%r11d
0x0000000002a40b54: and    %r11d,%r10d
0x0000000002a40b57: test   %r10d,%r10d
0x0000000002a40b5a: jne    0x0000000002a40c15  ;*return
```

That is, slower `return 0` is explained by more CPU instructions executed in `Blackhole.consume()`.

**Note to JMH developers:** I would suggest rewriting `Blackhole.consume` like

```
if (i == l1) {
     // SHOULD NEVER HAPPEN
    nullBait.i1 = i; // implicit null pointer exception
}
```

where `volatile long l1 = Long.MIN_VALUE`. In this case the condition will still be *always-false* but it will be compiled equally for all return values.

Comment: @AlekseyShipilev must be interested in that :)

Comment: this explains a lot. Thank you!

Comment: @apangin: That's an interesting idea, however: a) it does not scale to other data types, and we'd like to keep the consume-s consistent across the consumed types; b) it goes for widening conversion, which is bad for 32-bit platforms (think ARM).

Comment: The *real* takeaway from this example is that nanobenchmarks require validation on assembly level, which is convenient now with JMH's -prof perfasm :)

Comment: @apangin: if JMH isn't perfect, then which one is?